# Is the word "genuinely" redundant in this sentence (I have to genuienly agree with you)?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, redundancy

I replied to someone's text by saying, "*I have to **genuinely** agree with you.*"
However, the person told me that the word **"genuinely"** in this sentence is redundant. It dilutes the sentence.

Is it OK to use genuinely to emphasize more or sarcastically?
If it is redundant then why?

Here is the text history:

Person 1: Can you give some tips on how not to mix things up when I’m talking about multiple gifts?

Person 2" (Replied to Person 1): If you have trouble talking about multiple gifts then don’t talk about multiple gifts

Me (Replied to Person 2):I have to genuinely agree with you.  As it could become more complicated

Comment: If you said this at all, you would normally say, **I genuinely have to agree with you.**

Comment: I don't think it is sarcastic.

Comment: @Astralbee I am pretty sure. It was my reply. I made the sentence.

Comment: @Ghost apologies, I got so wrapped up in the meaning I didn't notice it was something you said rather than heard.

Comment: @Astralbee Please do not apologise. Do you think I am correct?

Comment: To be clear, it's not so much that it's "not OK"; the suggestion to remove it is *writing advice*, about making it *better*. The general principle is that your writing is more effective when you remove words that aren't "adding much" to the sentence. Also, it's advice that is "a bit picky"; I would give this advice if I were trying to make the writing *the best possible*, but not necessarily in all situations. Also, you haven't given the context: there could be situations where the word "genuinely" really is important (though maybe in a different place in the sentence).

Comment: If you edit to show more of the conversation and tell more about the meaning you wanted, you can get more focused answers.

Comment: If they made their point so well that you _have_ to agree with them, there seems no room for doubt that your agreement is genuine.

Comment: It's redundant in this context because you have already stated that you; "have to" agree, which means that your genuine opinion about the text message concurs with the person that sent it. I have to agree with you = I genuinely agree with you.

Comment: @AndyBonner Let me know please If I have to add more.

Comment: [correction: Can you give **me** some tips] genuinely is a very fancy word so it sounds funny here.

Comment: @Lambie I did not understand. Do you need some tips?

Comment: @ghost I agree that it *could* be a redundancy if you didn't need to say it! In my answer I explain that the meaning of 'genuinely' would counter any suggestion that you might not be genuine in what you say. If that is not in question, then yes, it is redundant. Either you agree with someone, or you don't, so there is no need for an additional emphasis word. You would only need to further qualify what you said if perhaps you *partially* agreed - maybe on some points, but not others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would only be redundant if the context or the circumstances made it so.

"Genuinely" adds the meaning that you are being genuine, or truthful, in what you say. Really, that would only be completely necessary if there was some doubt as to the genuineness of the reply. It might also be useful if the point being agreed with (sticking with your example) was perhaps unusual, or controversial, and the speaker anticipates some surprise at their agreement.

Some native English speakers do have a habit of using words like *genuinely, really, honestly, truthfully etc* simply for emphasis, rather than to qualify that something is true. This kind of use could be considered redundant if it added nothing to the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think the problem is redundancy, agreement isn't always absolute and can be subject to gradation or stress.

However, "genuine agreement" hits the ear wrong, at least for me.

You could substitute 'genuinely' with 'sincerely' to emphasize that you honestly agree with someone or something. Or "totally" to emphasize absolute agreement.